# How to remove a specific character from an array of pointers on string

Tags: c++

I have to remove the character c in every string in an array of pointers, but the compilator give an error and i dont't know how to solve. This is the code:

```cpp
for(int k=0;k<A[i][j]->length();k++){
    if(A[i][j]->at(k)==c){
        (A[i][j]->at(k)).remove();  //error here
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
[Error] request for member 'remove' in '(*((*(A + ((sizetype)(((long long unsigned int)i) * 8ull)))) + ((sizetype)(((long long unsigned int)j) * 8ull))))->std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::at<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((std::basic_string<char>::size_type)k))', which is of non-class type 'char'
```

Comment: When asking about a compiler error, it's helpful to actually show us the error that you're getting.

Comment: Please add that to the original question so it can be formatted a bit better :)

Comment: Probably don't want to call `remove()` on an actual character literal, but instead see how `remove()` should be called.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `remove()` on the `char` that `at()` returns, not on the `std::string` that you are calling `at()` on (and why are you even using `at()` at all? Your loop already ensures you don't go out of bounds, so the extra bounds checking that `at()` performs is wasted overhead you don't need).